# Python - dask: calling map_blocks and returning a new dimension error

Tags: python, dask

I am calling `map_blocks` with an 1d array and returning a 2d array as follows.

```
def compute(i):
    return np.array([i + 1, i + 2])

a = da.arange(30, chunks=10, dtype = np.uint64)
x = da.map_blocks(compute, a, dtype=a.dtype, new_axis=1, chunks=(6,10))
x.compute()
```

Which outputs this:

```
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
       [ 2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
       [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
       [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21],
       [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30],
       [22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31]], dtype=uint64)
```

If I change the last line to `x[1].compute()` I get the correct answer `array([ 2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11], dtype=uint64)`.

However, if I try to access any subarray that belongs to any other chunk, for instance `x[2].compute()` I get `IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2`.

Using `x[2].visualize()` I see what seems to be the error: dask is trying to get that subarray from the wrong chunk as shown below (it should call getitem from the middle one):

[image: Dask acessing the wrong chunk to get the answer]

Am I doing anything wrong? Perhaps messing with either `new_axis` or `chunks` parameters. I have no clue. Thanks in advance!